# Como puedo lograr que se redireccione correctamente una pagina utilizando el RedirectToAction?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estoy realizando un login para el acceso a un proyecto ya elaborado pero he tenido inconvenientes en como disponer del RedirectToAction pues me arroja el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La vista de Sidcar se encuentra en la carpeta de Home, pero no se porque arroja este error. El codigo del controlador es el siguiente:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace ProyectoDicar.Controllers
{
    public class UserController : Controller
    { 
        //
        // GET: /User/
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }

        private const string ControllerName = "Sidcar";
        Boolean boolean = false;
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(Models.User user)

        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (user.IsValid(user.UserName, user.Password))
                {
                    boolean = true;

                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Login data is incorrect!");
                }
            }
            if (boolean == true)
            {
                return RedirectToActionPermanent ("Sidcar", "Home");
            }
            return View( );
        }
        public ActionResult Logout()
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        public ActionResult Sidcar ()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Agradezco su colaboracion

Comment: En el controlador `UserController` tiene un metodo `SidCar` pero estas redireccionado a `/Home/SidCar/`. Seguro que hay un metodo llamado `SidCar` en el controlador `HomeController`?

Comment: Bienvenido a [StackOverflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com); si podes, agrega el código del `HomeController` específicamente la función `SidCar`, porque posiblemente ahí es donde este el problema

Comment: Probablemente quieras redireccionar a `/User/SidCar` en lugar de `/Home/Sidcar` o asegurarte de lo que Einer comenta, pero el error lo dice todo: no se encuentra lo que se busca.

Comment: Si efectivamente ese era el inconveniente, pues habia creado un controlador especificamente para la vista Sidcar. Agradezco su colaboracion al responder a mi inquietud

Comment: Podrías por favor hacer click en https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que ganes tu primera medalla y de paso obtengas el conocimiento en cómo funciona este sitio :D